# Ubuntu 20.04 development branch looks exactly like 19.10?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

So I updated my ubuntu 19.10 to development release 20.04 and it looks exactly like 19.10.
There are no changes in the GUI. I have been trying to update it to the LTS version 20.04 but I am unable to do that either as it says that the software is up to date.
Mainly used `update-manager -c -d` and tried `do-release-upgrade -d`

Distro:
on entering the command `lsb_release -a`
[image]

I would like to know how to update to the LTS version of 20.04 or what's known as Final Release.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you encounter any errors during your release-upgrade?

Comment: I know the difference between a final release and a development release, but when I intended to upgrade to 20.04 developmental release I wanted to check out the features for 20.04. And that did not work out either. Like the development release has the same exact UI as 19.10 and I am wonder why this is the case

Comment: I have not encountered any errors during the `release-upgrade`

Comment: So suppose the ability to change the themes (Dark, Light, Standard), or the suspend button, or the 20.04 backgrounds

Comment: Please always **[edit]** your question to provide extra details. Comments is not the right place for important info.